# Join won't do it, and sub query sucks, then what?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

first of all, sorry for the non descriptive title, I'm just too rushed so I couldn't come up with a better one. 
Second: 
 
I have a portion of my database the looks like the following diagram: 
 
[image]
I have contributors on the system, each write to many sources, and a source can have many working contributors. Users can subscribe to as many contributors as they like and as many sources as they like. Now, what I want to do is simply retrieve all the articles for certain user. These articles are either coming through a contributor or a source the user subscribes to. To make it easy, when a user subscribes to a source I simply copy all the sources contributors to the users_contributors table. One tricky piece, when I retrieve the user's articles I retrieve all the articles that he his contributors write, and all the articles that were published in the sources he follows where those articles doesn't have a valid contributor on the system. (I.E contributorID is null). 
 
I created the following query:

```
 Select Articles.ArticleID, Articles.ContributorId, Contributors.Name, 
    Sources.Name, Articles.ArticleTitle
From Articles 
            Inner Join Contributors On Articles.ContributorId = Contributors.ContributorId
            Inner Join Sources On Articles.SourceId = Sources.SourceID          
Where Articles.ContributorId in (
    Select ContributorId from Users_Contributors
    Where UserID = 3
    )
    OR (

        Articles.SourceId in (
            Select SourceId from Users_Sources
            Where UserID = 3
            )

            and 
            Articles.ContributorId is null
    )
```

The problem with the above query is that, it doesn't return any article with contributorID null. I understand this is because of the join on the contributors table. What should I do in such a  case?

1. **Should I consider denormalization?**
2. **What are the prober fields to index on each table for this query
   to run fast (Rowset returned are
   approximately 10000)?**
3. **I need to support paging on this query, will "With { }" clause be
   appropriate to me, or should I
   consider another strategy?**

   Thanks in advance. 
    
   ***Ps: I'm using SQL Server 2008***

Comment: @7alwagy: What did you use to draw the table diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, s.Name AS SourceName, NULL AS ContributorName
FROM    User_Sources us
JOIN    Articles a
ON      a.SourceID = us.SourceID
JOIN    Source s
ON      s.SourceID = us.SourceID
WHERE   us.UserID = 3
        AND a.ContributorID IS NULL
UNION
SELECT  a.*, s.Name AS SourceName, c.Name AS ContributorName
FROM    User_Contributor uc
JOIN    Articles a
ON      a.ContributorID = uc.ContributorID
JOIN    Contirbutors c
ON      c.ContributorID = uc.ContributorID
JOIN    Sources s
ON      s.SourceID = a.SourceID
WHERE   uc.UserID = 3
```

If you need paging, use this (to get the pages from `80` to `100`):

```
WITH    q AS (
        SELECT  TOP 100 
                a.*, s.Name AS SourceName, NULL AS ContributorName
        FROM    User_Sources us
        JOIN    Articles a
        ON      a.SourceID = us.SourceID
        JOIN    Source s
        ON      s.SourceID = us.SourceID
        WHERE   us.UserID = 3
                AND a.ContributorID IS NULL
        ORDER BY
                OrderDate
        UNION
        SELECT  TOP 100
                a.*, s.Name AS SourceName, c.Name AS ContributorName
        FROM    User_Contributor uc
        JOIN    Articles a
        ON      a.ContributorID = uc.ContributorID
        JOIN    Contirbutors c
        ON      c.ContributorID = uc.ContributorID
        JOIN    Sources s
        ON      s.SourceID = a.SourceID
        WHERE   uc.UserID = 3
        ORDER BY
                OrderDate
        ),
        page AS
        (
        SELECT  TOP 100 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS rn
        FROM    q
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    page
WHERE   rn >= 80
```

Comment: I need to join in Contributors and Sources in order to get contributor name and source name.  so .. !!

Comment: I'm not sure of the union would work for me. Here are my specific needs: I need to order the return records by Articles.OrderDate and support paging on those. Also on the second part of the union I have to join on the sources table to get SourceName (as it's not going to be null).

Comment: @7alwagy : The union should work. Its supported in sql server 2008. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just make this join

```
Inner Join Contributors On Articles.ContributorId = Contributors.ContributorID
```

an outer join?

```
Left Join Contributors On Articles.ContributorId = Contributors.ContributorID
```

That will cause it to return all Articles, whether or not there is a matching SourceID (includes cases where ContributorID is null).

Comment: oops I mistyped .. it's Join contributors on Articles.ContributorID = Contributors.ContributorId .. I edited, plz check again!